# write tasks to install nginx and postgresql using ansible-playbook

Tags: postgresql, nginx, ansible, yaml

.score.sh is given as

```
#!/bin/bash

pass=0;
fail=0;
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    worker=`ps -eaf|grep nginx|grep worker`
    master=`ps -eaf|grep nginx|grep master`
    serverup=`curl -Is http://localhost:9090/|grep -i "200 OK"`
    serverurl=`curl -Is http://localhost:9090/|grep -io "google.com"`
    if [[ ! -z ${worker} ]];then
        ((pass++))
        echo "nginx is running as worker";
    else 
        ((fail++))
        echo "nginx is not running as worker";
    fi;

    if [[ ! -z ${master} ]];then
        ((pass++))
        echo "nginx is running as master";
    else 
        ((fail++))
        echo "nginx is not running as master";
    fi;

    if [[ ! -z ${serverup} ]];then
        ((pass++))
        echo "Nginx server is up";
    else 
        ((fail++))
        echo "Nginx server is not up";
    fi;

    if [[ ! -z ${serverurl} ]];then
        ((pass++))
        echo "Nginx server is redirecting to google.com";
    else 
        ((fail++))
        echo "Nginx server is not redirecting to google.com ";
    fi;
fi;
echo $pass $fail
score=$(( $pass * 25 ))
echo "FS_SCORE:$score%"
```

i was only able to install nginx and postgresql but not satisy the conditions given in .score.sh
Can someone help me how do I install nginx as both master worker node and master and direct it to google?

Comment: There are Ansible [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html) that can do the tasks you are running through the script. Specifically - service, uri, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ---

#installing nginx and postgresql

- name: Updating apt
  command: sudo apt-get update
- name: Install list of packages
  apt:
  pkg: ['nginx', 'postgresql']
  state: latest
- name: Start Ngnix service
  service:
  name: nginx
  state: started
- name: Start PostgreSQL service
  service:
  name: postgresql
  state: started

if nginx not started use
'sudo service nginx restart'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and the fresco course did get passed for me.

```
---
#installing nginx and postgresql

- name: Install nginx
  apt: name=nginx state=latest
  tags: nginx

- name: restart nginx
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name=postgresql state=latest
  tags: PostgreSQL

- name: Start PostgreSQL
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---
#installing nginx and postgresql

- name: Install nginx
  apt: name=nginx state=latest
  tags: nginx

- name: restart nginx
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name=postgresql state=latest
  tags: PostgreSQL

- name: Start PostgreSQL
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started
```

I have tried the above one getting below error message

```
ERROR! 'apt' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

The error appears to be in `'/projects/challenge/fresco_nginx/tasks/main.yml'`: line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
#installing nginx and postgresql
- name: Install nginx
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers give above works on installing nginx, the problem is nginx is running port 80 and the score script check 9090. If you curl using port 80 you will get response. So you need to find some way to change the nginx conf file to use port 9090.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

Define your port number and the site you wish to redirect nginx server to in .j2 file in Templates folder under your roles.

Include a task in Playbook to set the template to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default folder. Include a notify for the handler defined in
'Handlers' folder.

In some cases if nginx server doesnt restart, use 'sudo service nginx restart' at the terminal before testing your code.

### Ansible-Sibelius (Try it Out- Write a Playbook)

#installing nginx and postgresql

```
- name: Install nginx
  apt: name=nginx state=latest
  tags: nginx

- name: restart nginx
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name=postgresql state=latest
  tags: PostgreSQL

- name: Start PostgreSQL
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started

- name: Set the configuration for the template file
  template:
    src: /<path-to-your-roles>/templates/sites-enabled.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
  notify: restart nginx
```

Comment: You posted [a nearly identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596860/how-to-redirect-nginx-server-to-google-com-after-restarting/70545263#70545263) to another question. Please don't do that. If the same exact answer can address two distinct questions, consider flagging one of them as a duplicate. If not, please customize your answer to address the specifics of the question.

Comment: The other question was posted by me couple of months ago. So wanted to close the thread with the answer and did that. The current question also speaks about the same hacker rank fresco play lab question. So pasted the same here.
Nevertheless thank you for letting me know, will make sure to provide link or flag as duplicate from next time. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I found below code useful and passed the frescoplay. and above mentioned code also passess the handson in frescoplay.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ensure nginx is at the latest version
      apt: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: start nginx
      service:
          name: nginx
          state: started
```

Answer (score -1):

server {
listen 9090;

```
    root /var/www/your_domain/html;
    index index.html; 

    server_name google.com;
   

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
    }
```

}

Comment: add this line in  /etc/nginx/share-enabled/

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: This is not an ansible task. You've written a nginx file.