# How to redirect nginx server to google.com after restarting?

Tags: nginx, ansible

stuck at an ansible hackkerrank lab(fresco play) that asks to install nginx and postgresql and ensure they are running.
But after finishing the code and running the exam it is checking for redirection of nginx server after restart to google.com.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Below is my code to install and ensure services are running:

```
name: 'To install packages'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    -   
       apt: 
         name: "{{item}}" 
         state: present
       with_items:
        - nginx
        - postgresql

   apt: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: start nginx
      service:
          name: nginx
          state: started
   apt: name=postgresql state=latest
    - name: start postgresql
      service:
          name: postgresql
          state: started
```

Wrote these in two separate playbooks as of now and need help in redirection of nginx to google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your nginx configuration file (in this case specifying to redirect traffic to google) and copy to the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

```
  - name: write nginx.conf
    template:
      src: <path_to_file>
      dest: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

After this you should restart the nginx service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

Below code worked for me:

Define your port number and the site you wish to redirect nginx server to in .j2 file in Templates folder under your roles.

Include a task in Playbook to set the template to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default folder. Include a notify for the handler defined in 'Handlers' folder.

In some cases if nginx server doesnt restart, use 'sudo service nginx restart' at the terminal before testing your code.

**Ansible-Sibelius (Try it Out- Write a Playbook)**

#installing nginx and postgresql

```
- name: Install nginx
  apt: name=nginx state=latest
  tags: nginx

- name: restart nginx
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name=postgresql state=latest
  tags: PostgreSQL

- name: Start PostgreSQL
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started

- name: Set the configuration for the template file
  template:
    src: /<path-to-your-roles>/templates/sites-enabled.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
  notify: restart nginx
```